# integrating spring boot reactive with graphql

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, reactive-programming, jetty-9

i am currently doing a POC to add graphql to a mono reactive spring boot project with uses jetty.
existing reactive spring boot configuration is

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
     exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:2.4.4"
implementation "io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.4.6"
```

springBootVersion = '2.1.16.RELEASE

which is working perfect.. when i add below graphql configuration

```
implementation "com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2"
implementation "com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:5.2.4"
implementation "com.graphql-java:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2"
```

and schema having simple subscription which returns mono and corresponding resolvers. when i treid to start the application loading all schemas and resolvers but at the end giving below exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverEndpointExporter' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer not available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
    at com.abc.abc.abcd.abcde.abcdApplication.main(abcdApplication.java:12) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.16.RELEASE.jar:2.1.16.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer not available
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter.afterPropertiesSet(ServerEndpointExporter.java:107) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1828) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

if i comment out jetty it is working perfect. am not getting whether i need to configure some severcontainer. if yes a sample code would be great help thank you..